# How do I call an existing contract from another contract in rust-ink?

Tags: substrate, rust-ink

I have two very basic `rust-ink` dapp contracts:

**Dapp 1**

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

use ink_lang as ink;
use dapp2;

#[ink::contract]
pub mod dapp1 {
    use dapp2::dapp2::Dapp2;

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Dapp1 {
        dapp2_instance: Dapp2
    }

    impl Dapp1 {
        /// Get existing `Dapp2` contract at `address`
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new(address: AccountId) -> Self {
            let dapp2_instance: Dapp2 = ink_env::call::FromAccountId::from_account_id(address);
            Self {
                dapp2_instance
            }
        }

        /// Calls the Dapp2 contract.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn dapp2_do_something(&mut self) -> u8 {
            self.dapp2_instance.do_something()
        }
    }
}
```

Dapp 1 specifies dapp2 as a dependency in the `toml`:

`dapp2 = { version = "3.0.0-rc7", path ="../dapp2", default-features = false, features = ["ink-as-dependency"] }`

**Dapp 2**

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
pub mod dapp2 {
    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Dapp2 {
        pub what: u8,
    }

    impl Dapp2 {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            let what = 2.into();
            Self {
                what
            }
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn do_something(&mut self) -> u8 {
            ink_env::debug_println!("{}", self.what);
            self.what
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this build, `dapp2` compiles but `dapp1` fails with

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `dapp2`
 --> /home/usr/dev/dapp-example/dapp1/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use dapp2;
  |     ^^^^^ no external crate `dapp2`
```

Even my IDE is able to find `dapp2` when clicking through so what's wrong with this import style?

I've seen other examples ([1](https://github.com/RainbowDAO/RainbowDAO-Protocol-Ink-Test-Version-05/blob/d14f67fc468c51260458644560fe2fe20500d2ad/rainbow_govnance/lib.rs#L8), [2](https://github.com/atenjin/ink-event-bug/blob/ab12702eb760bc82efd9affc81f10283a40c7af9/test/lib.rs#L5), [3](https://github.com/yangluo1024/ink_contracts/blob/5bcecb72bace20e99fc5b5d6b0fa8cf0d405abbd/elc/contracts/relp/lib.rs#L8)) where the contracts are simply imported into the module but this doesn't seem to work for me. If I do this, I get:

```
7 |     use dapp2::Dapp2Ref;
  |         ^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `dapp2`
```

Ink is set to `master` branch. Rust nightly is up to date. Edition is 2021. The example code is [on github](https://github.com/prosopo-io/dapp-example/tree/583e81730364e7e1b4b1268e759b2088c9078da6)

Comment: Hi Forgetso, please support our proposal to open a Substrate StackExchange site: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was not having the `crate-type` set as `rlib` in the `toml` files.

```
crate-type = [
    # Used for normal contract Wasm blobs.
    "cdylib",
    # This was not set
    "rlib"
]
```

https://github.com/prosopo-io/dapp-example/blob/5b31491bfa02ccd9603c1ac91f0907c2c9b84856/dapp1/Cargo.toml#L25